# How would I make a regular expression that would mean /some string/ either followed by a line break or not?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function(input){
    return input.replace(/teststring/ig, "adifferentstring");
}
```

I want to replace "teststring" and "teststring\n" with "adifferentstring"

Comment: @totymedli Javascript regex's don't need surrounding quotes (as a handful of other languages, such as perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex, to match a specific character you can place it in brackets:

```
[\n]
```

To make the match "optional", you can follow it with a `?`:

```
[\n]?
```

In your exact example, your full regex could be:

```
teststring[\n]?
```

So, your function would look like:

```
function replace(input) {
    return input.replace(/teststring[\n]?/ig, "adifferentstring");
}
```

I'd suggest going with matching characters in brackets as this makes for easy expansion; consider, for instance, that you want to match Window's newlines (a carriage-return + a newline):

```
teststring[\r\n]?
```

Comment: To the mass-downvoter, care to explain what was wrong with my answer (and the other answers) to merit a downvote?

Comment: I don't like the downvote system because it is rude to downvote people who put some effort to help people.

Comment: I don't even think it is someone who posted an answer, which is kind of irritating.

Comment: @invisal the downvote system is good for the purpose of raising the correct answer, also for denoting that there have been no correct answers, but it is sometimes abused and I also occasionally find myself upvoting useful responses that I normally wouldn't have just because some jerk abused his downvoting priveleges

Comment: ...and I believe a downvote is *never* useful without an explanation in the comments...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
function(input){
   return input.replace(/teststring\n?/ig, "adifferentstring");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `.replace(/teststring[\n]?/ig,"adifferentstring");`

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

```
var re = /teststring([\n]?)/ig;
```

So then your replace statement would look about like this:

```
return input.replace(re,"adifferentstring");
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXwLq/) showing the regex works.

And then a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXwLq/1/) showing the replace operation working.

### Edit:

Actually, thinking about the problem a little further, if your regex does match a carriage return or new line character, that would need to get put back into the replacing string. The same regex I posted originally will work but you will need this replace statement instead (with the `$1` denoting the first group in parantheses.

```
return input.replace(re,"adifferentstring$1");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXwLq/2/)